# Spring Boot Mongo DB Lookup AggregationOperation

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

First of I want to say am new to MongoDB, especially MongoData with Springs. I have the following collections

**Category**

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "categories")
public class Category {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    @CreatedBy
    private ObjectId creatorId;
    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime modifiedAt;
    @LastModifiedBy
    private ObjectId modifiedBy;
    private String title;
    private String notes;
    private boolean enabled = true;
}
```

Activity

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "activities")
public class Activity {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    @CreatedBy
    private ObjectId creatorId;
    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime modifiedAt;
    @LastModifiedBy
    private ObjectId modifiedBy;

    private ObjectId budgetId;
    private ObjectId categoryId;
    private String title;
    private String notes;
    private Double estimatedBudget;
    private boolean enabled;
    private boolean recurring;
}
```

I have come up with a simple query that joins the two collections which works to my expectation as below (... might also not be super cool query). The idea is i want to get all the activities grouped inside Category based on categoryId. Then afterwards, i only want to retrieve activities having a given budgetId.
I should be able to retrieve all Categories irregardless of whether activities within it exists or not, Like LEFT JOIN in SQL

```
db.categories.aggregate([
{

$lookup: {
        from: "activities",
        localField : "_id",
        foreignField: "categoryId",
        pipeline: [
              {$match: { $and:[{"budgetId": ObjectId("60f8ef1ed7056b730cdce1db") }] }}
        ],
        as: "activities"
    },
},
 {
        $match: {
            $and:[{"enabled": true}]
            }
        }

])
```

This works somehow.
So the question is how to I translate the above query to AggregationOperation in springs?

I have the following, but it excludes the Categories that dont have Activities within it.

```
  List<AggregationOperation> operations = new ArrayList<>();


        Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("enabled").is(true);

        operations.add(match(criteria));


        Criteria forBudgetActivitiesCriteria =  Criteria.where("activities.budgetId").is(budgetId);


        operations.add(lookup("activities", "_id", "categoryId", "activities"));
        operations.add(match(forBudgetActivitiesCriteria));

        TypedAggregation<Category> aggregation = newAggregation(Category.class, operations);
        AggregationResults<Category> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Category.class);
```

Am guessing the problem is here

```
Criteria.where("activities.budgetId").is(budgetId);
```

Help. And thanks in advance.

Comment: Does https://mongoplayground.net/p/wx7V-uCqFnA achieve your expected output? If so, I can help you to translate  in Spring boot

Comment: Having the `$match` stage _before_ the `$lookup` would be the appropriate (efficient and correct) way to build your query (assuming the field is from the `categories` collection).

Comment: @prasad_ I end up with an empty result when I use $match before the $lookup

Comment: @varman Yes it does thanks. I have only removed 
 {
                  $eq: [
                    "$enabled",
                    true
                  ]
                }
cos i only want to run the match on categories, no activities . I will be very grateful if you'd help translate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregation is

```
db.categories.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "activities",
      let: { "cId": "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: [ "$budgetId", "abc" ] },
                { $eq: [ "$$cId", "$categoryId" ] },
                { $eq: [ "$enabled", true ] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "join_activities"
    },
    
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wx7V-uCqFnA)**

There are two `$lookup`s in mongodb. One is standard lookup which is supported by spring data (LookupOperation class) and the second one is co-related subqueries lookup. Unfortunately spring data doesn't support it. But there is a **[Trick to convert](http://pingax.com/trick-convert-mongo-shell-query-equivalent-java-objects/)**

We can write it like Bson objects

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

public List<YOUR_CONVERTER_CLASS> test(String value) {

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        l-> new Document("$lookup",
                new Document("from","activities")
                .append("let",new Document("cId","$_id"))
                .append("pipeline",
                    Arrays.asList(
                        new Document("$match",
                            new Document("$expr",
                                new Document(
                                    "$and",
                                    Arrays.asList(
                                        new Document("$eq",Arrays.asList("$budgetId","abc"))
                                        .append("$eq",Arrays.asList("$$cId","$categoryId"))
                                        .append("$eq",Arrays.asList("$enabled",true))
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ).append("as","join_activities")
        )
    ).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());

    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(YOUR_COLLECTION_CLASS.class), YOUR_CONVERTER_CLASS.class).getMappedResults();

}
```

Note : This is not tested, but was written based on working mongo playground. Mongodb 5.0 has the same signature as you posted in post. If you need to convert your query, you can use the trick and convert, Its just a key value pair

Comment: Thank you @varman , I didnt know about the key value pair conversion. It has helped me achieve most of my problems with ease

Comment: If this is helpful, please have a look on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235